# Appium sends instructions without feedback, and manually slides the screen to react

Tags: android, appium

When I use Appium to automate the android 8.0 application, I can see that Appium sends an instruction to the phone, but the operation is not performed on the phone. When I swipe on the phone, it will actually perform the operation. But this situation does not appear in android6.0 (the same app), Appium version is 1.9.1, java-client version is 6.1. Who can help me, thank you very much。

Comment: And some bugs that didn't appear in android 6.0 appeared in android 8.0

Comment: Can you provide a narrower problem description, esp. with some sample code?

Comment: sure，my code like：driver.findElement( By......).click,it used in android 6.0,but it's unuserful in android 8.0